# Webapp getting slower with multiple ajax request

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, performance, ninject

I'm using ninject with an asp.net MVC5 application and I experiment weird performance behavior only with stacked ajax requests.

Looking to optimize the poor performance of a particular page, I placed a stopwatch between the `Application_BeginRequest` and `Application_EndRequest` (let's call it `A`) and one inside the called method in the controller (let's call it `B`).

The results are a consistent if I make std http requests (page call) the measurement made by `A` and `B` are quite in the same magnitude.

**Problem:** I display a page with 10 tables, feed by Ajax request. The 4 first requests shows normal behavior (`A` and `B` times are respectively 100ms and 80ms) while the 6 other show catastrophic performances: `B` stays around 80ms while `A` take up to **10 second**.

Is there anythin I can do to avoid such a disturbance, preferably on the server side of the application?

<sup>Do not hesitate to ask any information about the setup, I'll be glad to complete the question</sup>

Comment: have you tested each one of your tables independently? I'm curious if table #5 has a giant response size and is hogging all of the network bandwidth when trying to return your response.

Comment: @Keith.Abramo I observe the same loading time with an almost empty result (one or two rows) and with 100 rows

Comment: Performance is notoriously difficult to troubleshoot from afar. There's simply to many variables for someone outside your organization to give you any reasonable answer. This could be related to the type of database you're using, the version thereof, the resources on that instance, the network it resides in, firewalls, proxies, VLANs in place, etc. Or, it could be an issue with your web server, likewise with resource utilization, workers, App Pool configuration, etc.

Comment: At the very least, you should also post the code for the action that handles this AJAX request, as it's also entirely possible that your code is just inefficient.

Comment: Most likely suspects are 1) too many individual database calls (best to wrap them into a single call) 2) lack of caching (no need to get the same data again if another part of the app already did it - use HttpContext.Items[] to store data within the same request 3) too much going on in constructors - [injection constructors should be simple](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/), and MVC runs them for *every* request (so multiple AJAX calls can be an issue if you have something in your constructor that should be executed later).

Comment: That said, this question is too broad - try to narrow it down and post the relevant details here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the `SessionState` was the culprit here, setting it to `ReadOnly` using `[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]` drastically improved the performances of the Ajax requests.